# Google Analytics: Goals with regular expressions are not working

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-firebase

I know that it might be odd, but I need your help with the google analytics set up.

Task: I need to set up brochure downloads as a goal for international students on a page https://www.cqu.edu.au/international-students/international-brochures .

In a perfect world, I would need to set up an individual goal for each type of brochure download (postgraduation, undergraduate, English courses) but I decided to start from "all brochures" to save the number of goals that I have for the view. Unfortunately, I don't have a chance to set up "events", so I have to work with goals only.

Final goal destination: Any page containing "pdf_file" in its description.

Pathway: come to International section, move to brochures, then go to brochure page (containing "pdf_file" in its description, for ex. - https://www.cqu.edu.au/__data/assets/pdf_file/0005/158540/2017-Undergraduate-International-Guide.pdf).

The problem: I tried to use regular expressions such as "^/__data/assets/pdf_file/*." or ^/pdf_file/(*.) and I can't see conversions in real time test.

However, nothing helped, and goals (even the page visit) still aren't tracking correctly. What am I doing wrong? And, if possible, how can I split goals across different brochure types?

Many thanks,
Kirill

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right track. You just need one Goal. The problem you have is that after clicking a pdf document you are being redirected to a PDF viewer iframe. This is a PDF view "page" with no Google analytics tracking code whatsoever.If you use are using **destination goals** the only way this will work is by having installed the Google Analytics (GA) tracking code at the "final destination page".

One way to track pdf "views" is by [creating a short url](https://support.google.com/faqs/answer/190768?hl=en) for each one, hence you will be able to track or check how many of them have views.

Another way is to create an onclick **event** within each link. But this is only possible if you can setup the events in GA. Creating this kind of event tracking will allow you to set up labels for each pdf's name to be able to identify or track each one of them.